# Apache Flink Checkpoining (Manually put a value into RocksDB Checkpoint and retrieve during recovery or Restart)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpointing

We have a scenario where we have to persist/save some value into the checkpoint and retrieve it back during failure recovery/application restart.

We followed a few things like ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor still not working.
https://github.com/realtime-storage-engine/flink-spillable-statebackend/blob/master/flink-spillable-benchmark/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/spillable/benchmark/WordCount.java

https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-flink-stores-your-state-7b37fbb60e1a
https://github.com/king/flink-state-cache/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/king/flink/state/Example.java

We can't externalize it to a DB as it may cause some performance issues.
Any lead to this will be helpful using checkpoint. How to put and get back from a Checkpoint?

Comment: Your application looks okay. How are you testing the checkpointing? See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/#observing-failure--recovery for a tutorial explaining this.

Comment: is there a way to put and get some data into Checkpoint?  its fine if we code as well.

Answer (score 0):

All of your managed application state is automatically written into Flink checkpoints (and savepoints). This includes

- keyed state (ValueState, ListState, MapState, etc)
- operator state (ListState, BroadcastState, etc)
- timers

This state is automatically restored during recovery, and can optionally be restored during manual restarts.

The [Flink Operations Playground](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/#observing-failure--recovery) shows how to work with checkpoints and savepoints, and lets you observe their behavior during failure/recovery and restarts/rescaling.

If you want to read from a checkpoint yourself, that's what the [State Processor API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/libs/state_processor_api/) is for. [Here's an example](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/state-processor/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/training/exercises/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java).

Comment: Hi Davi, thanks for the response we have tried with Keyed State still our value is not getting stored/ retrived from checkpoint.  e.g.

Comment: private transient ValueState<String> wordCounter;
wordCounter.update(currentValue);
Open method wordCounter = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
       "wc",
       TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>(){})););

Comment: we also tried with private ListState<Long> state; and update the state in a RichFlatMapFunction still not able to get the value

Comment: What are you doing when you try to "get the value"? Are you saying that your checkpoints aren't being restored properly, or that `wordCounter.value()` isn't behaving as you expect during normal operation?

Comment: Keep in mind that with keyed state, the state being accessed and updated is automatically scoped to the key of the current event.

Comment: Hi David, yes when we try to wordCounter.value() during restart of the appliaction its getting null.  checked with using both Default and RocksDb checkpointing.  any suggestion.

Comment: In order for `wordCounter.value` to be non-null you must explicitly restart the application from a retained checkpoint or a savepoint, and you must be calling flatmap with a word that already been counted during the previous run. If you believe you are doing this correctly, please share a reproducible example, clearly explaining all of the steps required to experience the failure.

Comment: Hi David, your observation is right sending you code in two comment
public class Counter extends RichFlatMapFunction<Event, String> {
 
  private ValueState<String> wordCounter;
  public Counter() throws IOException {
  }

 @Override
 public void flatMap(Event value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
   String cV = wordCounter.value();
   log.info("1 " + cV);
   cV = cV == null ? value.getId() : "tempvalue";
   wordCounter.update(cV);
   log.info("2" + wordCounter.value());
   out.collect(cV);
 }

Comment: @Override
 public void open(Configuration config) {
  wordCounter = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("wc",TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>(){})));
 }
 }

when we restart the JM the value state is not getting restored. it beings with null again.

Comment: Sure, but having the right code isn't enough. You have to do the restart properly, and provide the right data.

Comment: Can you help us how to ensure proper restart and confg

Comment: Please look at the operations playground that I shared earlier. It shows how you can test this.